# Edit Sharepoint Forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm relatively new to SharePoint, I have no training just what I picked up on my own and what  I picked up from the former developer.

I need to edit a form, just the labels for some of the text boxes, but I have no idea how to do this. Can I edit some HTML via SharePoint designer or can you do it via the SharePoint interface, I can edit the page but there is no option to edit the labels associated with the text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this isn't an Infopath form but just the basic input forms for SharePoint lists and documents the descriptions that you're looking for are available within the settings of the fields themselves. I'm also going to assume that you're on SharePoint 2013 since you didn't specify a version, but the instructions below will help you to figure this out for prior versions as well.

1. Navigate to the list or document library that you would to edit
2. On the ribbon click *List* if this option isn't available you're likely in a document library in which case you should click *Library*
3. Once the ribbon appears click *List Settings* or in the case of a document library click *Library Settings*

On the page that appears you'll see a listing of your field names. Click the one you would like to change the tooltip for and in the page that appears you'll see a description field. This is what populates your hints (on your forms) and tooltips.

Comment: Sorry, left out that key bit of info, yes it's SP 2013, and it's a document library. It's not an info path form, It's a regular form if that's a thing. 

I have add info to the description but It is not what I want I'm looking to change the title of the text field on the form but I'd I'd rather not change the field name on the library as it will mean I'll need to change workflows also.